# Add own functions in views.py wagtail

Tags: django-views, wagtail

I have setup a wagtail website. It works great for postings like a blog and simply add new pages.
But what if I want to add some extra functions to a page. Like showing values from my own database in a table.
Normally i use a models.py, views.py and template.py. But now I don’t see any views.py to add functions or a urls.py to redirect to an url?

Don’t know where to start!
Or is this not the meaning of a wagtail site, to customize it that way?

Thnx in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly add additional data to pages. One option is to add the additional information to the context of a page type by overriding its `get_context` method. For example, [this page](https://www.caltech.edu/quick-links-alumni) is just a place to display a bunch of links. The links and the collections they belong to are plain old Django models (managed as snippets). And then there is a page model that queries the database like this:

```
def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
    collection_tuples = []
    site = Site.find_for_request(request)
    for collection in Collection.objects.filter(links__audiences=self.audience, site=site).distinct():
        links = Link.objects.filter(audiences=self.audience, collections=collection, site=site)
        collection_tuples.append((collection.name, links.order_by('text')))
    # sort collection tuples by the collection name before sending to the template
    context['collection_tuples'] = sorted(collection_tuples, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=False)
    return context
```

Another option is to do basically the same thing - but in a StructBlock. Then you can include the StructBlock in a StreamField on your page. Most of the Caltech site is written using blocks that can be included in one large StreamField on a page. Some of those blocks manage their own content, e.g. rich text blocks or image blocks, but others query data and render it in a block template.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I’m glad it’s possible what I want to accomplish. Gonna try things out.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @cnk's excellent answer - you can absolutely use views.py and urls.py just as you would in an ordinary Django project. However, any views you define in that way will be available at a fixed URL, which means they'll be distinct from the Wagtail page system (where the URL for a page is determined by the page slug that the editor chooses within the Wagtail admin).

If you're defining URLs this way, make sure they appear *above* the `include(wagtail_urls)` route in your project's top-level urls.py.